# Substituting table columns using Joins

Tags: sql, select, postgresql-8.4

Am not sure if the title is clear enough. What I want is so simple yet complex to achieve (maybe I am over thinking it). I think joins have the solution, though I don't know how to structure the join.

say we have two tables, cities and flight_profiles:

cities

city name | city code 
-------------+-------------- 
     city a   |      1 
     city b   |      2

flight_profiles

flight_numb | from | to 
---------------+-------+----- 
      701       |    1    |   2 
      702       |    2    |   1

And the query should display the following desired output

desired output

flight_numb |  from    |   to 
---------------+----------+--------
       701       |  city a   | city b 
       702       |  city b   | city a

How do I structure this join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flight_profiles` table already has the routes, you just need to replace the city codes with names. This can be done, as you suggested, by using joins - once for each code you'd like to replace:

```
SELECT flight_numb, cityfrom.name, cityto.name
FROM   flight_profiles fp
JOIN   cities cityfrom ON fp.from =  cityfrom.citycode
JOIN   cities cityto ON fp.to =  cityto.citycode
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `cities` table twice with different alias names

```
select f.flight_numb, 
       c_from.city_name as c_from, 
       c_to.city_name as c_to
from flight_profiles f
join cities c_from on c_from.city_code = f.from
join cities c_to on c_to.city_code = f.to
```